# How can I know the progress of formatting a USB?

Tags: usb, usb-drive, disk, gui, solus

So I'm using solus, but I'm sure that other Linux with GUI have the same problem.

I'm formatting my USB, which I go to file manager (GUI), click the drive to mount it, then right click and select format (I've choose the erase data option). But since there isn't any progress bar, how can I know when is it done and how much percentage is left if it's not done yet?

Will I get a notification, or can I know whether it's done by checking if the drive is listed on file manager (since it looks like when you start formatting it, it'll disappear in the drive list)?

Comment: Answer can be found in he following link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073416/i-cant-see-external-storage-device-formatting-progress